# Calculate difference between numbers in 2 columns row-by-row in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I have 3 columns in a Google Docs spreadsheet: A) Inventory purchased price, B) Inventory sold price, C) Difference between A and B (i.e. profit or loss)

Data is going to be entered manually into columns A and B. How do I make column C to 1) display the calculated amount for each row, and 2) color profitable sales in green and unprofitable in red?

Comment: For 2, you want "conditional formatting". There are already several questions here on that topic; just do a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.. and for the first question, assuming your data start in row 2, in C2 try:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A)*len(B2:B), B2:B-A2:A,))
```

This formula should automaticcaly output the difference between B and A when data is entered. See if that works ?

Comment: It worked fantastically.  Thank you very much!

Comment: How would I do it if all numbers are in one single column and I want to calculate the difference between the current row and the row above? Like =A2-A1 and make this continue down "forever".